# Link image from Storage in Firebase to CLOUD firestore document Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

This is the instance to push image to Storage in Firebase:

```
Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    Reference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('ifprofile/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) => print("Image uploaded: $value"));
  }
```

with this method I can upload images picked up from gallery or camera, now when the images is into firestore I need to link the specific image user to cloud firestore collection where I call this collection with Futurebuilder:

```
CollectionReference influencerUser =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerUser');
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              future: influencerUser.doc(firebaseUser.uid).get(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                   return here I need to call the images from the storage in firebase
```

as you can see above into my futurebuilder I call documents from cloudfirestore and I need to call also the image linked to storage to cloudfirestore.
how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here in `value` you have the url for the image:

```
taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) => print("Image uploaded: $value"));
  }
```

Simply save it as String in your Firestore doc. After that you can get that String from the doc and show the image using [Image.network()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) or [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image).

```
  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
     if(snaphot.hasData) {
        var inputMap = snapshot.data();
        print('firestore doc: $unputMap');
     }   
}
```